# iOS 10 speed dial - too fast for systems to recognize!

Tags: iphone, ios

iOS 10 had one surprise feature: The speed dial for adding a conference code to a call now dials much more rapidly.

In general, I appreciate this, but it has resulted in the code frequently being misparsed by the phone service, which means I have to dial the conference code manually; I usually don't have it at my fingertips, which results in a net slowdown for dialing in to (unfortunately frequent) phone calls!

Our firm uses Global ReadyConnect.

Has anyone else experienced this or found a solution?  I'd love to have it work just a bit slower, or worst case back to the pre-iOS10 speed.

Comment: Could you explain speed dial? Are you automating 888111222,,,23456 or is speed dial something else entirely?

Comment: I'm seeing the same issue

Comment: For example, when you click the Zoom phone number in a calendar invite, something like:  801-321-9876,,123456789# - after the pause (two commas) it’ll rapidly dial the meeting ID (1234…) followed by pound. Zoom can’t recognize the meeting ID, it’s dialed too fast!

Comment: I have only experienced this in the last iOS update 16.1.1 (I think) a sometimes the phone even trips over the dialing and somewhat jams two tones together (so they’re even shorter)

Answer (score 1):

I noticed this also and appreciate speed but I haven't had a problem with it being too fast. Have you tried adding commas in between each digit in the conference code? That may work for your particular use case.

For example

```
1(555)123-4567,,,1,2,3,4,5,6,#
```

Comment: I tried this and it makes the dialing painfully too slow. I've also had issues since iOS 10 with the remote system incorrectly parsing the new, faster speed dial.

Comment: Automatically-generated phone numbers (such as MS Teams, Zoom) show up in your calendar invite without the commas. So adding commas isn’t an option - is the same amount of effort as just typing the numbers (including meeting ID) manually.